# PythonAst and LanguageContext

Tags: python, ironpython

Is someone out there familiar with IronPython internals, specifically with PythonAst and LanguageContext classes ?

My application does compile a Python script source and then look into PythonAst to find variables. While I can successfully find global variables, I am unable to get functions' local variables. Is it possible somehow ?

Another question would be to also find the *current* type of a variable as it can be inferred from the compiled code as well as its current value ?

After a script was executed I can use the ScriptScope structure, or at debug time I can parse a debug frame for variables and theirs value, but I would like to do it at compile time also, as the user constructs the code. Is this possible at all ?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the type is resovled at runtime? I'll take a close look to it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I got help on another forum and found a solution. It is basically goes like this :

A FunctionDefinition has a body which will most likely be a SuiteStatement (which is just a collection of statements). Local variables will be defined with AssignmentStatements, where the Left side is an array of NameExpressions. From there you can figure out what the locals are, by gathering all of the NameExpressions.